# Add /category/ to an author archive page

Tags: categories, url-rewriting, author

I want to add /category/ to a author archive page to filter just the posts from a specific category from all the authors, something like this: `mysite.com/author/me/movies`

Is there a way to do it using a function? I know how to do using something like this `mysite.com/author/me/?category=movies`, but I want using correct permalinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a new rewrite rule using 'add_rewrite_rule`.

If the category is the default WordPress category, you won't have to register a `query_var` but if your category is a custom category, then you would have to register a `query_var` using the `query_vars` filter.

If **category** is the default WordPress category:

```
function wpse256215_custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^author/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&category_name=$matches[2]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'wpse256215_custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

If **category** is a custom query variable (author_category):

```
function wpse256215_custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^author/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&author_category=$matches[2]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'wpse256215_custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);

function wpse256215_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'author_category';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse256215_query_vars' );
```

To use the custom query variable in your template, you can then use the `get_query_var` function:

```
$author_category = get_query_var( 'author_category' );
```

**REFERENCE:**

- [**add_rewrite_rule**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)
- [**query_vars filter**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars)
- [**WP_Query**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)
- [**get_query_var**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var)

Comment: Works! Thanks @Tunji. Btw, the page title dont assume the author name or anything. Can I add something to this rewrite rule to configure how the page titles will work in this cases?

Comment: You should either edit your `archive.php` template file or use `the_title` filter

Comment: I had problem with pagination, and i did this: `function wp_author_plus_category () {
    add_rewrite_rule('^author/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&category_name=$matches[2]','top');
 add_rewrite_rule('^author/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/page/([0-9]{1,})/?','index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&category_name=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[4]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'wp_author_plus_category', 10, 0);` but don't work. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you paste a sample url with pagination? Plus your regex looks wrong

Comment: `http://cinemacomrapadura.com.br/author/siqueira/criticas/?theme=chazelle` the ?theme is for forcing the theme that I'm developing right now.

Comment: Can't see any page in the link you posted above, just `siqueira` and `criticas`

Comment: Theres a pagination on the bottom of the page, but any page returns the same posts, dont do correct pagination.

Comment: Paste the link in your address bar when you click on the next page link

Comment: `http://cinemacomrapadura.com.br/author/siqueira/criticas/page/2/?theme=chazelle`